# difference between Hybrid and Hardware decoding

Tags: ios, media-player, codec

For iOS Players (such as AVPlayer or oPlayer) exist Hybrid and Hardware decoding settings.
Both are designed for h.264 codec (for normally play HD files with h.264 codec).
I don't understand difference between them.

Can someone explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a decoder is labelled as a `Hardware` decoder, it means that the decoding is completely performed by a hardware block in the platform. When such *fixed function hardware blocks* are present, one of the main factors to consider is that the functionality would be limited i.e. only those features supported by the `hardware decoder` will be supported and in case, a new feature is required, you will have to go in for a *re-design* and *re-spin* of the same.

The main advantage of a hardware decoder is that it is usually power efficient as the hardware is specifically designed to implement the functionality. In addition to this, the overall system performance is also optimized by matching the formats of the  output of the hardware decoder block to the `GPU`.

When a decoder is labelled as a `Software` decoder, it is pure software based implementation of the codec running on the CPU. This implementation methodology helps to extend the functionality of the underlying codec as it is just replacing an older version of SW with a newer one.

The main disadvantage of a software decoder is that it will be power intensive. With large memory accesses for larger video resolutions, the power requirement for Software decoder increases heavily and drains battery faster. This is definitely not a good option for large resolutions and for long durations of playback.

`Hybrid` decoders are another class of decoders which integrate a software module that acts as a pre-processor typically with an underlying hardware engine. For example, if there is an underlying high performance `DSP` or `SIMD` engine, then the pre-processor can perform the serial portions of the decoding like CAVLD and other header/bit parsing operations, whereas the more complex mathematical part of operations like `Intra Prediction`, `Motion Compensation` would be performed by an underlying hardware block.

Some of the `Hybrid` decoders are also considered as `Hardware` decoders, but increasingly there are newer `Hardware` decoders available in the world today.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me any document about it?

Comment: Can we select which to use, software/hardware/hybrid decoder, for our iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

Hardware uses the GPU (or specific hardware) to do the video decoding.  Software uses the CPU to do the decoding.  Hybrid is a mixture of the 2.

These days the "hardware" moniker is increasingly becoming a misnomer ...